Do “extremely singular” functions exist?
Let $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be everywhere continuous, and differentiable with derivative $0$ a.e. with respect to $n-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure.
Is it true that $f$ is necessarily constant?

I think by letting $A$ be the set of where $f$ has derivative zero, between any two points of $A$ you can find a path between them contained in $A$, and in fact such a path which consists of line segments. It should be enough to show that through any point in $A$ there is a line contained in $A$, which intuitively seems true but I don't know enough GMT to know how to show that.

I misunderstood your question. You are right I believe it to be true. But one needs to show the complement of $n-1$ dim set is path connected.

Let $A$ be the the set where $f$ has derivative zero. Your assumption is that the $n-1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of the complement $B$ of $A$ is zero. Note that necessarily $A$ is dense, so it is enough to show that $f$ is constant on $A$.
Let $p,q\in A$. I claim there is some point $r$ such that the intervals $pr$ and $rq$ are both contained in $A$. If this is the case, then we get $f$ is constant on both intervals, and hence $f(p)=f(r)=f(q)$.
For notational convenience, let me assume $n=2$ and $p=(-1,0),q=(1,0)$. On the domain $D=(-1,1)\times\mathbb R$ consider the function $g$ which acts as radial projection from $p$ to the line $l=\{0\}\times\mathbb R$ if $x\leq 0$, or the radial projection from $q$ to $l$ if $x\geq 0$. $g$ is Lipschitz when restricted to $[-1+c,1-c]\times\mathbb R$ for any $c>0$, and therefore the image of $B\cap([-1+c,1-c]\times\mathbb R)$ has $n-1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure $0$ as well. The same is therefore true of the image of $B\cap D$, which is their countable union. In particular, this image is not all of $l$. Taking $r$ to be any point of $l$ not in the image, by definition of $g$ th intervals $pr,qr$ do not intersect $B$.

@Zerox Thank you, I mixed them up a couple times when writing, thought I fixed it all but apparently missed one.

@Zerox d stands for Dimension, n stands for dimensioN :) fixed

Very slick, nice.

If $f$ is not constant, we can assume that $f(a)\not= f(b)$ for all pairs of points of the form $a=(x_1,\ldots, x_{n-1},0)$, $b=(x_1,\ldots, x_{n-1}, 1)$ for $0\le x_j\le 1$. So all straight line segments connecting any $a$ to the corresponding $b$ must contain a point of the set $A$ where $f$ is not differentiable, or otherwise the mean value theorem would force $f$ to be constant between $a$ and $b$.
So if we want to cover $A$ by sets $E_j$, then their projections to the first $n-1$ coordinates must cover $[0,1]^{n-1}$. The $(n-1)$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of this projection is $\lesssim \delta^{n-1}$ if $E$ has diameter $\delta$. Since $\delta^{n-1}$ is exactly the quantity we are summing when computing $\mathcal H^{n-1}(A)$ this part of $A$ has positive $(n-1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

Why can you assume the condition at the start?

@Wojowu: If $f(s)\not= f(t)$, then by continuity also $f(x)\not=f(y)$ for any $x,y$ taken from small neighborhoods of $s,t$. By a change of variable, we can then assume the situation is exactly as described.
